# calculate the nth power of a matrix by induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix { {1,-h} ,{h,1} } for h=positive constant . How can I prove that the nth power of the below matrix is :

```
   1/2{{(1-ih)^n +(1+ih)^n, -i((1-ih)^n -(1+ih)^n} , {i((1-ih)^n -(1+ih)^n} ,(1-ih)^n +(1+ih)^n}}
```

I can prove this by assuming this type as something that applies for fixed n and using the principle of induction, but how could i have been lead to this type ? 
I have calculate the 1,2,3,4th power of the origin matrix but i can't find any relationship between them (except that they resemble with the infinite series of cosz and sinz) 
At this point I've been stuck... so I would appreciate any help !!

(I hope I made clear the problem) Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's easier to diagonalized the matrix by finding the eigenvalues even if you have an unknown but positive number in it

Comment: You can use MathJax to write equations in your questions. See the references here : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: well, with a quick calculation i see that the constant is not a problem at all, in finding the eigenvalues in order to diagonalize this matrix!! Thank you very very much!!